# Is it possible to disable kamon monitoring with Akka?

Tags: akka, kamon

I have a small project with Akka, and I use Kamon to monitor the actors. By default, monitoring is always enabled. But, is it possible to disable kamon?

Answer (score 2):

You can disable kamon by not including `kamon.conf` to `application.conf` (e.g. you have two separate config files, first only for kamon, second for whole app, in this case just comment line include `kamon` in `application.conf`). Another approach is using separate config files for testing and development: `application.test.conf` and `application.conf`, of course they must have specific configuration (it's up to you). For flexible leveraging of second approach, i recommend to use `ConfigFactory` class config assemble place (it makes life easier). Or if you just want to disable bothersome messages, you can use  `disable-aspectj-weaver-missing-error = false` this flag in conf.

Comment: Thanks for your help :) I am going to try this.

Comment: @Sergio Rodríguez Calvo Did it clarify the situation?

Comment: I could not try yet, sorry. I am going to try it in this weekend and I will say to you anything, do not worry ;).

Comment: Hi again! Sorry for delay in answering.

I can see this and it is not easy disable kamon. There is a flag called kamon.autostart=false but I got an error. To avoid that error, I have to exclude dependencies of kamon, that are: kamon-core, kamon-akka, kamon-akka-remote, kamon-scala and kamon-system-metrics.